# Refactoring 2 while loops so that they complete

Tags: php, algorithm, while-loop, combinatorics

I have a section of php code that I've written in order to create a random fixture list for 16 clubs that play 30 games each during a season. The problem I'm having is that the code never completes. If I reduce the number of weeks; $w, it starts to *sometimes* complete around 15, any higher than 20 and it never completes. Is there any way I can refactor this code so that it does eventually complete?

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit','960M');

$fixtures = array();

$drawnFixtures = array();

$allFixtures = array(
     [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9], [1, 10], [1, 11], [1, 12], [1, 13], [1, 14], [1, 15], [1, 16], 
     [2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8], [2, 9], [2, 10], [2, 11], [2, 12], [2, 13], [2, 14], [2, 15], [2, 16], 
     [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [3, 8], [3, 9], [3, 10], [3, 11], [3, 12], [3, 13], [3, 14], [3, 15], [3, 16], 
     [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [4, 9], [4, 10], [4, 11], [4, 12], [4, 13], [4, 14], [4, 15], [4, 16], 
     [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [5, 9], [5, 10], [5, 11], [5, 12], [5, 13], [5, 14], [5, 15], [5, 16], 
     [6, 1], [6, 2], [6, 3], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 7], [6, 8], [6, 9], [6, 10], [6, 11], [6, 12], [6, 13], [6, 14], [6, 15], [6, 16], 
     [7, 1], [7, 2], [7, 3], [7, 4], [7, 5], [7, 6], [7, 8], [7, 9], [7, 10], [7, 11], [7, 12], [7, 13], [7, 14], [7, 15], [7, 16], 
     [8, 1], [8, 2], [8, 3], [8, 4], [8, 5], [8, 6], [8, 7], [8, 9], [8, 10], [8, 11], [8, 12], [8, 13], [8, 14], [8, 15], [8, 16], 
     [9, 1], [9, 2], [9, 3], [9, 4], [9, 5], [9, 6], [9, 7], [9, 8], [9, 10], [9, 11], [9, 12], [9, 13], [9, 14], [9, 15], [9, 16], 
     [10, 1], [10, 2], [10, 3], [10, 4], [10, 5], [10, 6], [10, 7], [10, 8], [10, 9], [10, 11], [10, 12], [10, 13], [10, 14], [10, 15], [10, 16], 
     [11, 1], [11, 2], [11, 3], [11, 4], [11, 5], [11, 6], [11, 7], [11, 8], [11, 9], [11, 10], [11, 12], [11, 13], [11, 14], [11, 15], [11, 16], 
     [12, 1], [12, 2], [12, 3], [12, 4], [12, 5], [12, 6], [12, 7], [12, 8], [12, 9], [12, 10], [12, 11], [12, 13], [12, 14], [12, 15], [12, 16], 
     [13, 1], [13, 2], [13, 3], [13, 4], [13, 5], [13, 6], [13, 7], [13, 8], [13, 9], [13, 10], [13, 11], [13, 12], [13, 14], [13, 15], [13, 16], 
     [14, 1], [14, 2], [14, 3], [14, 4], [14, 5], [14, 6], [14, 7], [14, 8], [14, 9], [14, 10], [14, 11], [14, 12], [14, 13], [14, 15], [14, 16], 
     [15, 1], [15, 2], [15, 3], [15, 4], [15, 5], [15, 6], [15, 7], [15, 8], [15, 9], [15, 10], [15, 11], [15, 12], [15, 13], [15, 14], [15, 16], 
     [16, 1], [16, 2], [16, 3], [16, 4], [16, 5], [16, 6], [16, 7], [16, 8], [16, 9], [16, 10], [16, 11], [16, 12], [16, 13], [16, 14], [16, 15]
);


$w = 0;

while ($w < 30) {

    $g = 0;

    $games = '<ul class="fixtures">';

    while ($g < 8) {

        $randomKey = array_rand($allFixtures);
        $randomResult = $allFixtures[$randomKey];

        $homeTeam = $randomResult[0];
        $awayTeam = $randomResult[1];

        $fixture = $homeTeam . 'v' . $awayTeam; 

         if(!in_array($homeTeam,$fixtures) && !in_array($awayTeam,$fixtures) && !in_array($fixture,$drawnFixtures)) {   

            $fixtures[] = $homeTeam;
            $fixtures[] = $awayTeam;
            $games .= '<li>' . $fixture . '</li>';

            $drawnFixtures[] = $fixture;
            $g++;

        }

    }

    $games .= '</ul>';

    $w++;
    $fixtures = array();

    echo $games;

}
```

Comment: It is pretty unclear what it is that you are trying to accomplish here. How is the massive array of arrays structured and what does it mean? Also I would suggest using the `[1, 2]` notation instead of `array(1,2)`.

Comment: Think of the 1-16 as the ids of the 16 teams involved. Think of those arrays as a list of all the matches that need to be played in a season, the home team being represented by the first figure, the away team by the second. I'm trying to get the computer to create a complete fixture list, which would take 30 weeks (1 team playing the other 15 at home and away). What I want see is 30 lists that look like this with no repetition of any matches; 9v4 14v12 7v10 6v5 15v1 3v11 8v13 16v2. I've changed the notation to reflect your suggestion but it's had no real benefit.

Comment: Does `$allFixtures` contain all possibilities of 16 teams each of them playing with each other?

Comment: yeah, that's all the games that will take place in a season, just think of the comma as a 'versus'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying to get random value from fixtures, it's possible to have situations when you will have inappropriate conditions to get any value from `$allFixtures`. For example, check this output:

- Week 3, game 1: 9v10
- Week 3, game 2: 4v13
- Week 3, game 3: 11v6
- Week 3, game 4: 3v14
- !!! **Week 3, game 5: 2v5**
- Week 3, game 6: 16v1
- Week 3, game 7: 7v15
- Week 3, game 8: 8v12

Then

- Week 9, game 1: 13v4
- Week 9, game 2: 14v11
- Week 9, game 3: 10v7
- Week 9, game 4: 12v16
- Week 9, game 5: 1v15
- !!! **Week 9, game 6: 5v2**
- Week 9, game 7: 8v3
- Week 9, game 8: 6v9

And then

- Week 16, game 1: 16v12
- Week 16, game 2: 7v13
- Week 16, game 3: 8v15
- Week 16, game 4: 14v3
- Week 16, game 5: 4v1
- Week 16, game 6: 6v10
- Week 16, game 7: 9v11
- ???

As you see, best candidate for w16g8 is either 2v5 or 5v2, but at the same time both candidates are used already (w3g5 and w9g6). So, any shuffling initial fixtures will lead you to situations when a pair of teams cannot play because they already has played.

I'm not a mathematician and for this moment I have less knowledge about combinatorics than I wanted to have, but I can suggest randomizing values with this approach:

```
$template = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];

shuffle($template);

$allFixtures = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 16; $j++) {
        if ($i == $j) {
            continue;
        }

        $allFixtures[] = [$template[$i], $template[$j]];
    }
}

$output = '';

for ($week = 1; $week <= 30; $week++) {
    $this_week_players = [];

    for ($game = 1; $game <= 8; $game++) {
        foreach ($allFixtures as $key => $fixture) {
            if (in_array($fixture[0], $this_week_players)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (in_array($fixture[1], $this_week_players)) {
                continue;
            }

            $this_week_players = array_merge($this_week_players, $fixture);

            $output .= sprintf('<li>Week %s, game %s: %sv%s</li>', $week, $game, $fixture[0], $fixture[1]);

            unset($allFixtures[$key]);

            break;
        }
    }
}

echo sprintf('<ul class="fixtures">%s</ul>', $output);
```

This will give you appropriate distribution of team pairs, as well as this will eliminate a situation you have meet in your code.

I think, your code (even it has a lot of unnecessary bodily movements) will work fine even if you just will change the way of creating initial mixtures, not the whole approach, as did I. The main thing is the way of distributing team pairs in the initial list of mixtures. Your code is stopping response because it is looping and looping again for searching a value which is already used before and cannot be used now.

Comment: In fact, it never has 239 useless records in the list, searching for the 240th. The records in `$allFixtures` are pairs of teams and the code aims to select a pair of teams and to not pick a team twice. On the last step it already selected 14 teams; let's say they are the teams numbered from 1 to 14. The last step needs to pick the pairs that contain 15 and 16. There are 2 such pairs: `[15, 16]` and `[16, 15]`. The chance to find one of them is 2 out of 140. Apart this minor technical aspect, your explanation is correct.

Comment: @axiac when you have `$w = 29` and `$g = 7`, you have 239 records in `$drawnFixtures`; you are performing `$randomKey = array_rand($allFixtures);` in this case, which has 0.5% chance to get unique value.

Comment: @axiac because you are selecting not teams, you are selecting a 1/240 value from `$allFixtures`

Comment: @axiac The `$allFixtures` has 240 values, right? :)

Comment: Hmm... or I didn't understand the original code. It generates all the matches for a season (30 weeks), right?

Comment: @axiac exactly. But also now I better understand your goal. Do you want only one game for a team for one week? One team cannot have 2 games during a week, right? If so, the algorithm must be a bit changed.

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation: the first half of my original answer doesn't solve the question. The second half is correct though.

Comment: @axiac Oh, sorry, looks like I just thought that you are the question author, so I asked some questions related to the original code, not your code in your answer. Sorry. Next time I will pay more attention to nicknames.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, but this code provided more than one fixture for some teams in any given week.

Comment: @JordanD Actually, you was asking about how to refactor code in order to improve its speed. I gave you some info and a code illustration how to improve it. For now, I've updated it to be fully working for your case. But, please, next time when you will ask "how to improve it" question, do add mark "I want you improve it, not me". I will then skip such question because I usually skip questions where somebody ask to write code for them.

Comment: Thanks for trying again anyway Sergey, maybe I should have put more details in my question but there was a character limit, I've just tried the above code you said you'd updated and, though it isn't providing duplicates, it isn't providing 8 games a week either. I don't want you to write the code for me, I just don't understand how the code can work for me when it is providing these results.

Comment: @JordanD I have updated my answer again. Looks like I did not fully understand the problem you meet. It was more in math and in a way team pairs were distributed across `$allFixtures` after randomization. I also beg your pardon for my previous talks about "how to improve it" and "I want you improve it, not me" phrases; I thought it was an easy task to improve other code, but the other code was the problem, not code I've changed initially.

Comment: That appears to work like an absolute dream thanks Sergey. Thank you for all your help and for sticking with me, it really is much appreciated.